# Converting a while loop in a do-while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

I know this question has been asked several times already. Feel free to mark it as a duplicate. Anyway, I'd rather ask the community since I am still uncertain.

I should convert this while loop in a do-while loop.
Any thoughts?

```
public class DoWhile {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
           int sum = 0;
           System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)"); 
           int number = input.nextInt(); 
           while (number != 0) {
               sum += number;
               System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)"); 
               number = input.nextInt();
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: You'd help all readers of your question if you formatted your code section with indentation and correct line breaks. Please consider to edit.

Comment: Seems like code review kind of question. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You cant just simple convert any while loop to do while loop , the main difference between them is in do while loop you have an iteration that will happen regardless of the condition.

```
      public class DoWhile {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
             int number=0;
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); int sum = 0;
          do{ System.out.println("Enter an integer " +"(the input ends if it is  0)"); 
          number = input.nextInt(); 
          sum += number;
      }while (number != 0) ;


       }
       }
```

Comment: I already know this, in fact, this is an example from dr. Liang "Introduction to Java" Book.

Comment: That's much clearer now, thanks. Sorry everyone for the hassle

Comment: This will not compile since you have declared number inside the loop.Fix this and you are ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DoWhile {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
   int sum = 0;
   int number = 0;
   do {
          System.out.println("Enter an integer " +
          "(the input ends if it is 0)");
          number = input.nextInt();
          sum += number;
   } while(number != 0)
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class DoWhile {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); int sum = 0;

           System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)"); 
           int number = input.nextInt();
           //You need this if statement to check if the 1st input is 0
           if(number != 0)
           {
               do
               {
                    sum+=number;
                    System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)"); 
                    number = input.nextInt(); 
               }while(number != 0);

          }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the program to continue doing something in the "do" block. In your own case you have to tell the program to keep doing this"
   **System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)");     number = input.nextInt();** 
    **sum += number;"**. Then in the "while" block you will have to provide the terminating statement, in your own case "**number != 0**"

```
public class DoWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int number;        
        do {     
            System.out.println("Enter an integer " + "(the input ends if it is 0)");
            number = input.nextInt();
            sum += number;

        } while (number != 0);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

classInfoClass

```
{
   public void setinfo()


    {
        int  userage;


        do

        { Console.Write("Please enter your age: ");


         } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out userage));
```